# Where can I find a ByteUtils implementation to do String operations (indexOf, split, etc.) on a byte array?

Tags: java

I will be using byte arrays instead of String so I need to perform String operations on them. Of course I cannot create a String from them and get the byte array back after the operation. I need to perform the operation on the spot, something like below:

```
   int x = ByteUtils.indexOf(myByteArray, (byte) 'a');
```

**EDIT1: Assuming ONE byte => ONE char (no unicode, this is ASCII).**

EDIT2: I need a bunch of string operations, not just indexOf.

Comment: Arrays.binarySearch ???? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: Byte arrays are not interchangeable with strings, definitely not in a Unicode world like Java: multibyte characters and locale differences would make this approach a total waste of time, so there is no standard implementation for this. For simple operations (like that search in your example) standard array facilities can be used; for complex operations you shouldn't do them on a byte[].

Comment: @SergeyBenner binary search only works on sorted arrays, which clearly a byte[] containing a generic string **is not**.

Comment: @Viruzzo: *"multibyte characters and locale differences would make this approach a total waste of time"*...  Not if you're working with 'strings' which you know won't contain more than 256 different 'codes'.  Remember that not all string do contain "text".  There's a reason people took the pain to write Java APIs doing fast-string matching on both *char[]* and *byte[]* (see my answer, linking to Johann Burkard's *high-performance pattern matching algorithms*).

Comment: @TacticalCoder he specifically talked about Java Strings; if your values are just byte or char arrays it's not correct to talk about strings: their values could be conceptually mapped to anything (from characters to types of bunnies or whatever), and as such string-specific operations would make no sense on them. Of course if you make assumptions on the values (i.e. they are ASCII codes) you can implement all sorts of stuff on it (like those matching algorithms), but Java and any developer that use Unicode will not bother implementing that for you.

Comment: Edit1: This is ASCII. One byte => One char => end-of-the-story. Plus I said I did not want to convert to anything. :)

Comment: @Viruzzo: *"he specifically talked about Java Strings"*. No, he talked about String-like operation. *"if your values are just byte or char arrays it's not correct to talk about strings"*. That is **totally wrong**: people talk about 'string' and 'substring matching' all the time when talking about, for example, strings made of only ATGC. Google for "DNA string matching" to see you're wrong. Moreover people do talk about "alphabet" all the time for things that are **not** real letters and that do **NOT** form text when combined. Yet these are strings and you can do string-like operation on them

Answer (score 1):

For searching into a byte array you can use the `Knuth-Morris-Pratt Pattern Matching Algorithm`, see for example [this implementation](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/search-a-byte-array-for-a-byte-sequence)

Depending on what type of `indexOf` you want (character or full string).
For some other operations does [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) with `ArrayUtils` or the equivalent in [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) may suffice for your requirements ?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do that type of operation because you are mixing Bytes and Characters.  You either have to assume an character encoding (I think you are assuming ascii in your question), or you'll need to use the character encodings of the Java platform which means you'll need to convert it to at least a character array using some Charset.

The issue here is that char in Java is 2 bytes, and you're thinking you'll work with a single byte.  Anyway, if you really want to do this and not use the tools provided you're probably going to have to write your own because general speaking people writing open source tools are going to assume full use of the toolkit unless this is some common problem which I doubt it is.

So you'll have to write your own version of these, here's an example:

```
public int indexOf( byte[] bytes, String stuff, String encoding ) {
    byte[] pattern = stuff.getBytes(encoding);
    int startIndex = 0, patternIndex = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < bytes.length && patternIndex < pattern.length; i++ ) {
       if( pattern[patternIndex] == bytes[i] ) {
          if( patternIndex == 0 ) startIndex = i;
          patternIndex++;
       } else {
          patternIndex = 0;
       }
    }
    return patternIndex == pattern.length ? startIndex : -1;
}
```

You could try this library:  http://code.google.com/p/byteseek/

Comment: I was implementing this by hand, but got tired after some time. indexOf, compare, startsOf, equal, copy... It would be nice to have this utility class done somewhere, but again, I am looking for a BUNCH of methods, not just indexOf.

Comment: Granted I realize this.  It was just to illustrate how to deal with multi-byte issues.  What's confusing about your question was the example code provided where a character was passed in the indexOf operation.  That assumed you were using characters or parts of strings to do your matching against.  That's where this doesn't make a lot of sense to constrain yourself to no conversion.  However, if you had been working generically with byte[] this makes a little more sense.  Your intent isn't explained all that well, and why you are avoiding conversion to String.  Edited my answer.

Comment: Strings generate garbage. I treat everything as byte[] to avoid that. So I read from the network into a byte[], do what I need to do, and write to the network as a byte[]. No garbage is ever created. I know, it sucks, but that's what I need to do.